# unicode right arrow SAS

Tags: unicode, sas, output

I could not get to work the use of a right arrow  (U+2192) in the following Txt-output.

```
    data _null_;
    set WORK.CLASS nobs=nobs end=eof;
    file '&outpath.\test.txt' dlm=',';
    If _N_=1 then Put "&name.";
    Put (_all_)(+0);
    if eof then do;
       Put "(here should be the right arrow) $$ here is a lot of text$$";
    end;
    run;
```

Comment: Did you try the `unicode` function ?  How are you viewing the output file ?

Comment: Your code doesn't include it that we can see and we can't run it because the data set isn't available. This shows nothing related to you attempting to actually solving the problem, just an output to text data step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unicode` function (as @richard mentions), eg as follows:

[image]

For more info, see [documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=nlsref&docsetTarget=p1s61kmqg61m29n109i6dz4ivkbw.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).  Also note the macro variable in your file statement will not resolve due to use of single quotes.  Try the following:

```
data _null_;
set WORK.CLASS nobs=nobs end=eof;
file "&outpath.\test.txt" dlm=',';
If _N_=1 then Put "&name.";
Put (_all_)(+0);
if eof then do;
   Put "%sysfunc(unicode(\u2192)) $$ here is a lot of text$$";
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting character.  It seems to cause a lot of trouble if you write it to the SAS log.  Works once and then causes exception, at least with SAS 9.4 (TS1M3 MBCS3170).

```
NOTE: AUTOEXEC processing completed.

1          
2          data _null_;
3            putlog 'Here is an arrow ' "%sysfunc(unicode(\u2192))" '.'
4                 / 'Here is another arrow ' 'E28692'x '.'
5            ;
6          run;

Here is an arrow →.
Here is another arrow →.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.35 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


7          
8          data _null_;
9            putlog 'Next step.' ;
10         run;

Next step.
^L2 The SAS System                                                                                      17:42 Monday, February 5, 2018

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


11         

ERROR:  An exception has been encountered.
Please contact technical support and provide them with the following traceback information:

The SAS task name is [DATASTEP]
Segmentation Violation

Traceback of the Exception:

/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sas(+0x15aa8e) [0x2afdf8bdca8e]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sas(+0x4cb0b) [0x2afdf8aceb0b]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/tkmk.so(bkt_signal_handler+0x144) [0x2afdfa2193c4]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x389e40f790) [0x2afdf9185790]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwuunico(unicget+0xb3) [0x2afe2aeff343]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sasxfnc(yfxfn+0x1ff) [0x2afe28c9d69f]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxmac(yjsysf+0xe74) [0x2afe1db084d4]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxmac(yjoch+0x2c55) [0x2afe1db195d5]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxshel(ytscan+0x2543) [0x2afe0b2886d3]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxshel(yjdelta+0x33) [0x2afe0b26e183]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxshel(yjnext+0x95) [0x2afe0b2724d5]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxshel(ytokap+0x6a) [0x2afe0b27fb0a]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxshel(yttknx+0x32c0) [0x2afe0b27f2a0]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sasdsc(dsctok+0x26) [0x2afe2a50ce76]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/dbcs/sasexe/sasxshel(ysprstm+0x523) [0x2afe0b295b93]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sasdsc(dsccomp+0x198) [0x2afe2a4ea428]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sasds(sasds+0x1a7) [0x2afe299ffd47]
/Volumes/app/sas/test/sas9.4/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/sas(vvtentr+0x13d) [0x2afdf8ace6ad]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x389e407a51) [0x2afdf917da51]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x2afdf9b3b93d]

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
12         data _null_;
13           putlog 'Here is an arrow ' "%sysfunc(unicode(\u2192))" '.'
14                / 'Here is another arrow ' 'E28692'x '.'
15           ;
16         run;
17         


18         data _null_;
19           putlog 'Next step.' ;
20         run;

Next step.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```